# Why passing arguments to parent template makes the child template not be able to use them

Tags: django, parent, extends

im making a django project for school website

I have a base.html that acts as parent template for the child templates which is the content of every page

The base.html includes a navbar with the school logo and a section on it titled "Units"

this is the code to render a lecturer page

views.py
.
.

```
def lecturer_home(request):
    user = request.user

        query for the user first name and full name
        query for the units that the user is teaching and their teaching 
        period in unit_list and period_display


        class_display = zip(unit_list, period_display)
        user_dict = {
        'f_name' : user.first_name,
        'fl_name' : user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name,
        'class_display' : class_display,
        }
        return render(request, 'Lecturer/lecturerdashboard.html', user_dict)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Unexpected error')
```

lecturerdashboard.html extends the base.html

I put less code for my views.py because I don't think I made any errors. What I want to confirm with you all is, the user_dict I passed in lecturerdashboard.html can also be used in the base.html, but confusingly I find that if a key and value is used in either one, the other one cannot use it.
for example, I am able to display the units in the content section in the lecturerdashboard.html but when I used class_display in the base.html to show units as dropdown menu selection when the lecturer click on Units, the content section will not work because it doesnt understand class_display.
sorry if the question is confusing
in summary, the parent and child understands the argument passed by the view but if a key, value is used in parent, the child does not understand it
i just want to confirm, is this true?
thank you

Comment: Hi nanakondor , it would depend on how you are using the values passed by views in a template. If you could post the code in template demonstrating use of class_display we may be able to shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with templates. `zip` is an iterator. Once you iterate through it, it is exhausted, and can't be used again. If you want to iterate it multiple times, call `list` on it:

```
 class_display = list(zip(unit_list, period_display))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood clearly:
You want to have access to some of the variables like class_display in every template ?
If so the best solution for that is to use Context Processors. Example:

1. Create file in your app for example context_processors.py

```
from users.models import UserMessage


def notifications(request):
    if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        notifications = UserMessage.objects.filter(
            receiver=request.user, read=False)

        ctx = {
            "notifications": notifications,
            "notifications_number": notifications.count()
        }
        return ctx
    return {}
```

2. In settings.py in 
   TEMPLATES --> 'context_processors' add:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'app_name.context_processors.notifications' # added this!
            ],
        },
    },
]
```